# Append src in iframe

Tags: iframe, append, vimeo, src

I have a vimeo video loading through a dynamically created iframe on my site. For mobile devices i need to change the src from:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/220535146?controls=0&hd=1&autoplay=1&player_id=banneroneVid&api=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" title="reebok_short_loop" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen frameborder="0" id="banneroneVid" ></iframe>
```

to

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/220535146?background=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" title="reebok_short_loop" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen frameborder="0" id="banneroneVid" ></iframe>
```

Ideally i would like this to happen as the page is loading.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries to load the iframe you want depending on the device.

Something like this: (e.g. if you're using bootstrap)

```
<!-- bigger screens -->
<div class="hidden-xs col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/220535146?controls=0&hd=1&autoplay=1&player_id=banneroneVid&api=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" title="reebok_short_loop" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen frameborder="0" id="banneroneVid" ></iframe>
</div>

<!-- mobile devices with max-width: 768px -->
<div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/220535146?background=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" title="reebok_short_loop" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen frameborder="0" id="banneroneVid" ></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: thats a good idea but in this case the URL is being generated as the site loads so i think i need away to read the URL and then change it via php or jquery